# Undefined property: Craft\WebApp::$request

Tags: error-message, request

What could cause Craft to not define the request object?

I have a local site that recently stopped loading (front-end and back-end)

The error is happening in WebApp.php (line 630) when `$this->request->getBrowserLanguages()` method runs.  The script fails because `$this->request` is not defined.

Other Craft installations work just fine.  This site works just fine on a dev and live server with the same code. Any ideas on what I bumped?

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace leading up to the error?

Comment: Just sent you an email with it (didn't want to post the path info here)

Comment: It looks like this has been caused by a new line that was added in the general.php 'cacheMethod' => 'apc'.  I'm guessing I don't have this installed locally.  Still looking into this and will update when confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue turned out to be caused by a config setting that had been added to `general.php`

```
'cacheMethod' => 'apc'
```

The server had APC installed but my local environment did not.  There were a couple options to fix this:

1. Install [Alternative PHP Cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) (APC)
2. Setup a multi-environment config and override the `cacheMethod` setting with another method that is supported in your local environment, such as `'cacheMethod' => 'file'`
3. Remove this line as it may not be needed anyway. `apc` is PHP byte caching and if your running PHP 5.5, that's enabled by default and `apc` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. But I was using memcache.

It turns out it was acually memcached which is a slightly different extension.

Enable the setting in the memcache.php config file with

```
'useMemcached' => true,
```