# Getting error when using bootstrap: Craft\WebApp::$request

Tags: bootstrap-craft

I am using a testing library and while trying to load Craft through bootstrap with:

```
$craft = require '<full path here to>/app/bootstrap.php';
```

(but with the real path)

I dumped the error to a html file from the console and get this:

[image]

I see that Ben Parizek got a similar error (but i don't believe it was while using bootstrap only from the command line) in [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2081/undefined-property-craft-webapprequest).

I tried setting cache to file in general.php and also cleared all caches in craft.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in WebApp::init() and make sure that method is getting called?

Comment: I'm guessing there is some other error that's occurring and is getting swallowed by this error. Can you xDebug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got testing working by requiring the tests/bootstrap.php  (not app/bootstrap) like here: https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.loath/blob/master/tests/run.sh#L6